# Excel macro causes strange behaviour

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Hi there quite new to Excel macros im working on one here that sorts using the autofilter. It works fine and does what I want just when I try to resort the data it shows it within the wrong sheet. Anyway here is my macro

```
Sub Hide_Unassigned()
Worksheets("Resource View (2)").Activate
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Z1:Z200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
If c.Value = "Unassigned" Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort. _
    SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D200"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As i said everything works fine except when I attempt to re-sort the data in master data it shows up in the resource view (2) sheet. It can then be removed by simply dragging over it but I dont think thats sufficient.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help

Answer (score 0):

Had a brain wave and managed to sort this myself by simply moving the last part of the macro to be called when I access the master data sheet itself.

Comment: Glad you sorted it! Two suggestions: 1) Post your fixed code here in your answer (edit it and paste it in) so others can benefit from your changes. 2) I'd still recommend that you get away from `Active*` (as I recommended in my answer) because it will eliminate issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Active(anything)`. This is what will happen when you do.

Add:

```
Dim MstrDataWS as Worksheet
Dim ResWS as Worksheet
Set ResWS = Worksheets("Resource View (2)")
Set MstrDataWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")
```

Then, every time you want to reference one worksheet or the other, use `MstrDataWS` or `ResWS`, as appropriate. That will ensure you're referencing the correct sheet. It also allows you to eliminate all references to `.Activate` and `.Select`.

Also, `Cells()` and `Range()` refer to whatever the active sheet is, so you can get lost there. Adjust those commands to use `ResWS.Cells()` or `MstrDataWS.Cells()` as appropriate.

Comment: Cool thanks for the help I had just been recording my actions and making up the base of the macro that way and so have all the active stuff in there. Any chance you could tell me how the index and match functions search. is it from top down or from bottom up, I have a function using this to populate a field after the above sorting is done but it seems to give back a different answer in the field everytime just trying to get my head around the problem

Comment: Yup, that's default macro recorder type code. Nothing wrong with starting there, it's a great way to learn. Just be aware of the dangers of `Active*` and remove those bits after you've recorded. Your `Index()` and `Match()` questions are good, and I don't have the answer to that. Sounds like good fodder for a whole new question!